# Making a link in a tumblr post re="nofollow"

Tags: tumblr, html

Ive got a tumblr post that ive written, i would like to make one of the links in the post `rel="nofollow"` i seem to remember doing this in the past by being able to edit the html of the post ive composed, but i now cant seem to be able to that - Is that correct ? Or is there another way to make a link in a post `rel="nofollow"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When composing a new post, click on the gear icon in the top-right corner.

There’s a line "Text editor" which has the following options:

- Rich text
- HTML
- Markdown

Select "HTML", then you can write something like:

```
<a href="http://example.com/" rel="nofollow">link</a>
```